# GCC quad size 32 and 64 bit

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compilation

I'm using `GCC` compiler on Linux.
I want to use 64 bit compiler and build some of my files with `-m32` option (32 bit compatibility). I found strange (for me) behavior of compiler.
My code is simple:

```
int main () {
   int test =(((0) & 0x00000000) << (32));
   return 0;
}
```

And for this code I received warning for `32`, `64` and `64` with `-m32` compilers:

```
warning: left shift count >= width of type [enabled by default]
```

But when I'm trying to compile it from `assebmly code`:

```
.quad (((0) & (0x00000000)) << (32))
```

I received warning only  for `32 bit` compiler:

```
Warning: shift count out of range (32 is not between 0 and 31)
```

Why warnings are differ for same code compiled from `c` and `asm` file for different compilers (32 and 64 bit)?

EDIT:

Where can I find `.quad` definition, i mean in code?

Comment: Well, one is from the C compiler, and the other from the assembler, there seems to be no point to make the errors be exactly the same, as long as they contain the same information. Btw. why is this tagged as C++?

Comment: @PlasmaHH Ugh, sorry I don't want to add `c++` to tags...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 64 bit mode, gcc uses the LP64 convention.  This means that `long` and pointers are 64 bits wide, but `int` is still only 32 bits wide.  In the expression

```
  int test =(((0) & 0x00000000) << (32));
```

the constants are all assumed to be `ints`, because `int` is big enough to hold them all, and `int`s are always only 32 bits.  The result of a shift >= width of the type is UB in C because the behaviour is generally dependent on the underlying architecture's shift instruction.

Suppress the warning by forcing one of the numbers to be 64 bit.

```
long test =(((0) & 0x00000000L) << (32)); // Still gives a warning with -m32
```

or

```
long long test =(((0) & 0x00000000LL) << (32)); // No warning, long long is always 64 bit
```

Comment: Thanks for full answer. But why when I'm compiling asm code results (warnings) differ?

Comment: And also how can I add `LL` to the macro definition or to the `asm` file?

Answer (score 2):

In C, the type of the left operand of the shift is `int`, which is 32-bit on both platforms in question, so the shift is always undefined behaviour in terms of the C language.

I imagine that in your assembler the operand is either 32 or 64 bit, respectively.

Comment: In fact he is using `.quad` so that makes it 64 bit even in 32 bit mode. If the assembler is producing a warning, that's a bug or a limitation.